# Docker run command in User Data of EC2 fails to run

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, user-data

I am creating a cloud formation script for my application setup. I am adding the docker run command in the user data section of EC2. Docker run doesn't execute while everything else in user data executes. Below is my user data section

```
#!/bin/bash -xe
/usr/bin/docker run -d -p 80:80 -p 443:443 qa/myapp:2.4.2
```

Comment: Can you paste the error you are observing? It should be in cloud-init-output.log file in /var/log on your EC2 instance after it launches

Comment: I cant find that file. I am using Rancher OS ami

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how this works on Rancher OS. The user data needs to be in this format for Rancher OS

```
#cloud-config
 rancher:
 write_files:
   - path: /etc/rc.local
     permissions: "0755"
     owner: root
     content: |
       #!/bin/bash
       wait-for-docker
       docker run -d nginx
```